# BugZilla Installation error

Tags: web-services, bugzilla

Software error:

```
Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 28.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 50.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Error.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Error.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 31.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 31.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/html/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/html/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (root@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

This is the error given on executing the file index.cgi in server

Comment: I have also the same error. I am using `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009`, perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3), bugzilla-5.0, Apache/2.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mostly looks like a missing library. You can gets informations on this by looking at the output of:

```
./checksetup.pl --check-modules
```

see: [Bugzilla Installation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/installation.html)

If this is not sufficient for you, you would need to post more informations here ( version of Bugzilla, os, etc... )

Alexis

Edit:

The original error indicate a missing module: at least you will need to install Math::Random:ISAAC. The full missing requirements should be displayed by *checksetup.pl*, but it seems in some occasions this also crashes when ISAAC is missing ( see [4.2: checksetup.pl crashes when Voting extension enabled](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.bugzilla/browse_thread/thread/3972c886a64f2db8?pli=1)  )

Comment: i m using fedora 16 and bugzilla latest version

Comment: Then please consider installing package perl-Math-Random-ISAAC with your favorite package installer

Comment: The system says that all the required packages installed already. But when running getting the same error.